# Get an instance to evaluate to something by default

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following `AND` class:

```
class GATE:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        inputs = args or list(kwargs.values())
        assert (len(inputs) >= 2), "Must have two or more inputs for a gate."
        self.inputs = [int(i) for i in inputs]
    # def __repr__(self):
    #     return str(self.output)


class AND(GATE):
    @property
    def output(self):
        return int(all(self.inputs))
```

I would like to be able to do things like:

```
AND(1,1)
```

And it to return `1`. Not just print that value but actually evaluate to it so I can do something like this:

```
AND(1,AND(0,1))
```

How would I do this in a pythonic way? Otherwise I have to do:

```
>>> AND(1,AND(0,1).output).output
0
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a class at all - `AND` should just be a function.

Comment: Maybe make `AND` a method of `GATE` class?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes perhaps in the above snippet it makes sense. Keep in mind there are various other methods and gates and other things I haven't included.

Comment: @David542: Whatever those "various other methods and gates and other things" are, they don't change the fact that this doesn't make sense. If you tell us what other factors have driven you to this strange approach, we may be able to tell you what you should be doing instead.

Comment: Maybe you want `AND` to have methods, in which case `AND` should probably be a function with some attributes set, or an instance of a redesigned `Gate` class. Maybe you want `AND(1, 0)` to have methods that `0` doesn't have, in which case someone will probably suggest subclassing `int`, but it makes more sense to just change your API.

Comment: @Ch3steR -- thanks, I've used that approach and it works pretty well.

Comment: If you're going to make use of inheritance here, just define a set of rules for the other factors/gate operations to consider in the `__init__`

Comment: If you only care about states `0` and `1`, maybe `__bool__` is the method you're looking for? It expects `False` and `True` to be the values, but it doesn't actually enforce that. And it will be called by default by your current output implementation in `and` (by `all`, when it processes your inputs).

Comment: @Blckknght use `bool` instead of `int` you mean? Or where you do mean? `>>> bool([0,0,0])
True`

Comment: @David542 `bool(Truthy)-->True` and `bool(Falsy)-->False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way for a value returned from a call (like `AND(1, 0)`) to be both an instance of the `AND` class, and the number `0`. Either you get the instance, or the integer result, but you can't get both.

Or not exactly both. You can build your class so that the instance *behaves like* an integer in some contexts. If you add an `__int__` method, for instance, your class will be convertable to an integer if you pass it to `int()`.

Some other types can be even more easily converted to. If all gates are expected to have a binary output value, `0` or `1`, you can perhaps get what you want (automatic evaluation) by implementing the `__bool__` method on your classes. This method is used by Python when evaluating if an object is "truthy" or not. So `if AND(...)` would evaluate as you'd expect, as would `all([AND(...), AND(...)])` (which might be handy for *implementing* the `AND` class).

Note that the boolean values `True` and `False` are equal to the integers `1` and `0`, respectively. The `bool` class is a subclass of `int`!

Here's how I'd make your classes using `__bool__` (rather than `output`):

```
class Gate:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.inputs = args or list(kwargs.values()) # note, no int() calls made here
        assert (len(self.inputs) >= 2), "Must have two or more inputs for a gate."

    def __bool__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()  # subclasses are expected to override this method

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}(*{self.inputs})=>{bool(self)}>"


class And(Gate):
    def __bool__(self):
        return all(self.inputs)
```

Now you can do something like `result = And(True, And(True, False))` and you'll get an `AND` object saved to `result`. But `bool(result)` will give you the value `False`. Getting the `repr` of the class will also evaluate its Boolean value (so it can include the `True` or `False` result in the `repr` string).

Note that we don't do any kind of conversion of the inputs we're given (no `int()` calls). This means the code can work lazily with other kinds of inputs that don't have a steady value, like one based on reading from a file on disk, or prompting the user:

```
class Input:
    def __init__(self, prompt):
        self.prompt = prompt

    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(int(input(self.prompt)))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Input: {self.prompt}>"
```

If you do `lazy_result = And(Input("A: "), Input("B: "))` then doing `print(lazy_result)` or `bool(lazy_result)` will prompt the user for integer values, and evaluate the desired output. Note that because of short-circuting in `all`, if you enter `0` at the first prompt, it won't ask for the second one because it doesn't need to know the B value to give the value of the `And`! (That might not be desirable in some situations, so you might need to replace `all` with something that doesn't short circuit.)

Answer (score 1):

Using Ch3steR's suggestion you could make these methods to make a more uniform return:

```
AND = GATE.AND

class GATE:
    def AND(self, *args, **kwargs):
        inputs = list(args or kwargs.values())
        return int(all(inputs))      
    def OR...

AND=GATE().AND

>>> AND(1,AND(0,1))
0
```

You could potentially also pull it out of the class and make it a function as one of the other comments suggests, which would make it much more straightforward for this:

```
def AND(*args, **kwargs):
    inputs = list(args or kwargs.values())
    return int(all(inputs))

>>> AND(1,AND(0,1))
0
```

Comment: You've defined `AND` as an instance method, but you're trying to use it like a static or class method. Also, `AND = GATE.AND` won't work until after `GATE` is defined.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yea, that's a good point -- it should be an instance and not a static/class method as each gate needs to interact with others.

Comment: @FishingCode yes thanks for pointing it out. Now that I'm playing around with it a bit more I don't think the above approach is too useful.

Comment: This class design still doesn't make sense. If `AND` is to be an instance method, what is an instance of `GATE` supposed to represent? It's still not clear why `GATE` exists at all.

Comment: @David542 no problem, although I agree it can be tedious to it this way, you may want to add the "logic" gate determination for 0 or 1 within the functions...

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica something like this is what I'm trying to do with different electrical gates: https://github.com/djhworld/simple-computer

Comment: @FishingCode: `AND(1,AND(0,1))` seems like a perfectly fine thing to write with the function approach.

Comment: @David542: If you're trying to write a hardware emulator, I can see a few reasonable things `AND` could be, depending on exactly what you want it to represent and the level of detail you want to emulate. It could just be a function with `AND(1, 0) == 0`, or it could be a more detailed representation of a hardware gate with stuff like gate delay and state. If you go for a more detailed approach, then it doesn't really make sense to have your interface look like `AND(1, 0) == 0` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the computation in the way you want does not imply "returning" something from the constructor. Look at it this way: if you have a direct input, you process it; if you have a gate, you want its output.

See a version of how it can be done:

```
class GATE:
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.inputs = args or list(kwargs.values())
    @property
    def output(self):
        raise Exception('This should be overridden')

class AND(GATE):
    @property
    def output(self):
        result = True
        for i in self.inputs:
            if issubclass(i.__class__,Gate):
                result = result and i.output
            else:
                result = result and i
        return result
```

then the code you'd run can be something like:

`AND(True,True).output`

for a simple gate. It can also be

`AND(AND(True,AND(False,False)),True).output`

And you get the desired effect of processing each of the gates' outputs without writing `output` everywhere.

You could take it further and base this off of reduce and make the GATE children only have to define the lambda used to `reduce` the arguments, but that's another question.